# Screen sharing aps for Linux server

Tags: server, screen, sharing

Good afternoon everyone!
I am a little newbie to Linux and all this staff, but I have made server for TeamSpeak and other app for me and my friends, we are just missing one thing in one game adventure:
Is there any application which will allow us to for example connect via browser or client to server and share our gameplay and also desktop view sometimes (something like Discord can do) but Discord very often lags and provide low quality. So summary:
Application to stream via VPS in "room" with native quality and audio.
I couldnt find anything in google or I am just trying to hard if the are other simpler ways :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options I can suggest:

### Host a standalone RTMP server and open the video stream in VLC Media Player.

You can use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to stream directly to your new server and then relay it to another format such as HLS or another RTMP feed.
There are several products you can use as an RTMP Server.

- NGINX RTMP Module

If you're already familiar with NGINX configuration this this may be fairly easy to setup, see full documentation [here](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/modules/rtmp-media-streaming/).

- [Simple Real-time Server](https://ossrs.net/lts/en-us/)

This is a much more extensive and actively maintained project, it's a little more difficult to compile and configure but the documentation is not overly complex and the community is active to help.

### Host a full stream website with Owncast

[Owncast](https://owncast.online/) is marketed more as a Twitch replacement but it can suit your needs. The Owncast setup process will handle the RTMP relay for you and will provide a website and chat where viewers can watch your stream. Like the above you stream to it using OBS.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and time!
Are those things allow me and my friends to stream in same time and we can watch streams in windows close together? Let me explain: we are playing ETF, fps game where you dont have any marks above characters, so we have to know excatly our locations to avoid killing ourselves :) In Discord we can see for example 3 windows, 3 perspectives close to each other but quality is very dissapointing :)

Comment: @GeorgeWashington Sadly these suggestions probably aren't quite right for that, although I think Owncast would be most suitable I think you can have multiple channels it could be worth looking into. You might also want to [try this](https://pop.com/) although I haven't tried it myself it could work well for you.

Comment: Thanks one more time, gonna read about all of them :) It would be just very simple if TeamSpeak would have finally screen sharing but we are all waiting and waiting...